# Storing a big factor graph using linked lists

Tags: data-structures, graph

Could you please tell me can we use adjacency linked lists to store a big factor graph (an undirected factor graph with 500,000 nodes and around 1,000,000 edges) considering each node is a vector? If we cannot, what is the best option for factor graph implementation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, although using arrays will be more compact than linked lists.

If the factor graph has a fixed regular structure (e.g. a grid or a long HMM) then you could do away with the adjacency lists entirely if you index your nodes to take advantage of the structure.